# Property observers and their behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, properties, swift3

I've a sample class and a property of type `Int` like so:

```
class StepCounter {
    var totalSteps: Int = 0 {
        willSet(newTotalSteps) {
            print("about to set steps to \(newTotalSteps)")
        }
        didSet {
            if totalSteps > oldValue {
                print("Added \(totalSteps - oldValue) steps")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Now when I make an instance of this class and assign a number to my var `totalSteps` like so:

```
let anObj = StepCounter()

anObj.totalSteps = 2000
```

I get the console output as expected:

```
about to set steps to 2000
Added 2000 seteps
```

But when I do `anObj.totalSteps -= 1`, I get only the `willSet` output saying `about to set steps to 1999` and the `didSet` never gets executed. What is happening and why I'm not getting the `willSet` print statement executed? Do help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `didSet` you have:

```
if totalSteps > oldValue
```

But when you do `anObj.totalSteps -= 1`, the total steps are not greater than the old value!

So the `print` is not executed, as expected. :)